# Storing barcodes as ASCII

Tags: encodings

I am currently looking at a TIFF file generated by a microscope vendor. They store an XML within the TIFF (ImageDescription tag). Within this XML I can find a `<barcode>` element. But instead of storing the actual barcode (PDF417, DataMatrix) value, they store something else.

I have three samples, first one is a PDF417, the last two are DataMatrix. Decoding the values leads to:

1. `04050629C`
2. `H13150154711A11`
3. `H13150154512A02`

while the XML element `<barcode>` contains (in that order):

1. `MDQwNTA2MjlD`
2. `SDEzMTUwMTU0NzExQTEx`
3. `SDEzMTUwMTU0NTEyQTAy`

What type of encoding is this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of encoding is Base64 encoding.

```
$ echo MDQwNTA2MjlD | base64 -d
04050629C

$ echo SDEzMTUwMTU0NzExQTEx | base64 -d
H13150154711A11
```

Comment: Try to elaborate a bit (or just drop a comment).

Comment: Genius ! $ echo MDQwNTA2MjlD | base64 --decode -> 04050629C